# Depth First Search in python Error : Key Error 7

Tags: python, algorithm

[image]

I have written following python program to perform a **DFS** for the given graph, but after execution it gives the error : **Key Error 7**. What is wrong in my code?

```
output=[]
graph = {
            9:[8,7,6],
            8:[5,4],
            6:[3,2],
            5:[1,0]
        }

def dfs(graph,root):
    stack=[]
    visited=set()

    stack.append(root)
    output.append(str(root))
    visited.add(root)

    while not(stack==[]):
        for item in graph[root]:

            if item not in visited:
                stack.append(item)
                visited.add(item)
                output.append(str(item))

            if set(graph[item]).union(visited)==visited:
                stack.pop(-1)
                root=stack[len(stack)-1]
                continue

            root=item

dfs(graph,9)
print(" ".join(output))
```

---

Still the problem is not solved after adding suggestions given by @amit i have written the following code and it is giving incorrect output, please help!

```
output=[]
graph = {
           1:[2,3],
           2:[4,5],
           3:[6,7],
           4:[],
           5:[],
           6:[],
           7:[]
        }

def dfs(graph,root):
    stack=[]
    visited=set()

    stack.append(root)
    output.append(str(root))
    visited.add(root)

    while not(stack==[]):
        for item in graph[root]:

            if item not in visited:
                stack.append(item)
                visited.add(item)
                output.append(str(item))

            if set(graph[item]).union(visited)==visited:
                stack.pop(-1)
                if not(stack==[]):
                    root=stack[len(stack)-1]
                else:
                    break
                continue

            root=item

dfs(graph,1)
print(" ".join(output))
```

Comment: Can you somehow provide a more comprehensive error report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your graph implementation does not have nodes with `d_out(v)=0` as keys.

So, in this line:

```
        if set(graph[item]).union(visited)==visited:
```

When you put 7 (or 4) as `item`, you try to access `graph[7]` - but there is no such key.

You can overcome it by either changing the graph implementation to have a `key:[]` for all keys (including those with no out-edges), or by adding a check to the condition to check if `item` is in `graph` before attempting to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define the edges going from the vertex number 7.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @codegeek Actually, I think this *is* an attempt to answer the question. It's short and simple - and perhaps it's wrong - but it does try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to absent index value or column serial number.
What you can do is you can add index column in your data frame and then use pandas iloc syntax to loop through each row.
Ex: df.iloc['index number'].columnname