# DFS incorerct output using python

Tags: python, algorithm

[image]I asked a similar question but after incorporating changes also it is giving incorrect output, please help!

**Previous Question**
[Depth First Search in python Error : Key Error 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865818/depth-first-search-in-python-error-key-error-7/22868714#22868714)

**Current Code :**

```
output=[]
graph = {
           1:[2,3],
           2:[4,5],
           3:[6,7],
           4:[],
           5:[],
           6:[],
           7:[]
        }

def dfs(graph,root):
    stack=[]
    visited=set()

    stack.append(root)
    output.append(str(root))
    visited.add(root)

    while not(stack==[]):
        for item in graph[root]:

            if item not in visited:
                stack.append(item)
                visited.add(item)
                output.append(str(item))

            if set(graph[item]).union(visited)==visited:
                stack.pop(-1)
                if not(stack==[]):
                    root=stack[len(stack)-1]
                else:
                    break
                continue

            root=item

dfs(graph,1)
print(" ".join(output))
```

Comment: Could you give the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: without the output you expect to get it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: @JoranBeasley Now i have provided a picture

Comment: what are you actually doing DFS is typically used as a search for a specific node or value ...

Comment: @AndresPena please note you have enough reputation to vote up (as well as accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your working too hard ...
DFS is easy to implement

```
output=[]
graph = {
           1:[2,3],
           2:[4,5],
           3:[6,7],
           4:[],
           5:[],
           6:[],
           7:[]
        }

def dfs(graph,root):
    stack=[]
    visited=set()
    stack.append(root)


    while stack:
        node = stack.pop() #remove last
        if node in visited:
           continue
        visited.add(node)
        output.append(str(node))
        children = graph[node]
        stack.extend(children)



dfs(graph,1)
print(" ".join(output))
```

if you want the output to match exactly as you have it you will need to change

```
stack.extend(children)
```

to

```
stack.extend(children[::-1])
```

Comment: Yeah your code is giving correct answer, please don't mind but i don't understand what is extend function is doing here, please can you explain or provide some link..

Comment: `a_list.extend([1,2])` is the same as `a_list.append(1);a_list.append(2)`

Comment: You don't even need a stack. `dfs(graph, x, from=None): output.append(x); [dfs(graph, y, x) for y in graph[x] if x != from)]` (replace the list comp with a loop). That is for a tree, not a general graph.